# How to remove the media query with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to ask you guys about below case.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .shopping{
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .shopping .shopping-item {
        height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 1px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .shopping .shopping-item img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I would like to remove the above media query along with its classes with Jquery.
I don't know is that possible or not to remove the media query with Jquery as I don't know much about jquery.
Please kindly advice me.

Comment: is this from external link?

Comment: yes @guradio. It is from external link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Removing media query from external css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070565/javascript-removing-media-query-from-external-css-file)

Comment: @RahulMeshram I would like to remove it with jquery not javascript.

Comment: you can use javascript instead of jquery but not vice versa(iff jquery library is not there).

Comment: @RahulMeshram Actually I saw that post before I ask this question. But If it can be remove with jquery, the code can be more easier and simple i think. I will also try with javascript as you suggested.

Comment: jquery is a javascript library. It means that anything you do with jquery you do with javascript.

Comment: of course i know that @KoshVery. Just want to know if it can be removed with jquery. If not, I will try with javascript.

Comment: It is not possible with clean jquery, but there could be a plugin.